# Force superscripts for operators in jqMath

Tags: javascript, mathml, jqmath

I am using `jqMath` to display chemistry formulas on a website. I need to be able to display charges as superscripts (i.e., positive + and negative charges  -). It seems like `jqMath` (or maybe `MathML`) hardcodes all math operators to display as normal size. I've tested this with `+`, `-`, `=`, and `%` signs and none will display as superscripts (tested here: http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html). Note that

```
<sup></sup>
```

is not valid markup when using `jqMath`; the ^ precedes any character to be superscripted.

Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the superscript in `{}`: `$H^{+}$` (or `$\H^{+}$` to avoid italics).

Comment: Thank you very kindly! I racked my brain for awhile before posting here and definitely wish I had done so sooner.